# Unable to join wireless network

Tags: windows

How do I reset windows network adapter?

Having many issues with wireless networks etc.

I have tried `IPCONFIG /release` but didn't help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have anymore info? I think this may be of use to you though. Try this in an admin context CMD and then reboot your compurter.

```
netsh winsock reset
```